# CloudFront ignores Cache-Control headers

Tags: nginx, amazon-cloudfront

CloudFront ignores my cache header and my pictures have to be picked up from the server again after a while.

```
~$ curl -I http://d2573vy43ojbo7.cloudfront.net/attachments/store/limit/64/3720c5574063aebc90511061b99de858740ad764c6981d2bf30ff121ada0/image.jpg
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: image/jpeg
 Content-Length: 1645
 Connection: keep-alive
 Server: nginx/1.4.1
 Date: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 14:37:41 GMT
 Status: 200 OK
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
 Access-Control-Allow-Method:
 Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=31536000
 Expires: Fri, 12 Feb 2016 14:37:41 GMT
 Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image.jpg"
 Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 14:37:41 GMT
 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 X-Request-Id: 239b0fda-cae9-452f-9d1b-ccbf035bbf69
 X-Runtime: 3.457939
 X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
 Via: 1.1 6cde3c778df412041adc7610331b57bc.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
 X-Amz-Cf-Id: yicAkZYc5XpowKRFMOXDKSJKBMWZ4kq2B3vLK8Q-Py124D8lQq_1lg==
```

I tried to get the same file yesterday and then it was the same, after the second time i tried it was reached and served by CloudFront but not anymore. It's the same for all my images. They are cached but are removed from the cache after a couple of hours.

What's wrong? My cache behavior settings on CloudFront is set to default and it uses Origin Cache Headers.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I've been digging without any luck. I'm getting the same result as you.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I started to catch my assets through Nginx instead of just using CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html

> If an object in an edge location isn't frequently requested, CloudFront might evict the object—remove the object before its expiration date—to make room for objects that are more popular.

It means that object is not popular enough to stay in cache for a longer time. If you have enough viewers hitting this object AND this particular CloudFront location, it would have stayed in cache longer

Comment: the problem is that none of my images are popular. right now it's only me as a developer tht requests the files. When is a file popular and how can i stop CloudFront to delete cached objects?

Comment: Simple answer - you can't do it. While requesting object periodically might seem like a solution, in fact it is not - the best you can do is keep object in one CloudFront POP you are hitting. Once you will get real traffic it will be cached in the POPs near your customers

Comment: What is the main reason you want to keep the object in CF cache?

Comment: My image thumbnails are generated on the fly and it takes like 20 sec to generate a thumbnail. if i use custom and set minimum ttl to one year would that help?

Comment: I think the best (and only valid) solution here is to make sure generated thumbnail images are persisted and are available on the origin location when they are required. Tweaking with CloudFront settings won't that files will stay in cache any longer, as CloudFront is not a storage service, it is a cache.

Comment: my backend forces me to use the setup with the images that i have today. I have made some tests with same image and it is deleted from the cache before 12h. How can CF decide that a image is unpopular so fast?